# Naive quick sort in Clojure

Tags: clojure, quicksort

I'm learning clojure and wanted to crate my naive quick sort. This implementation cuts array (vector) in half and process them recursively. Issue is that this code happens to throw NullPointerException when array (vector) is of size 1 just at the end of recursion. Why is that ?

```
(ns qsort)

(defn qsort [arr] 
(println "arr" arr)
(def cnt (count arr))
(def pivotidx (if (> cnt 1)
  (int (/ cnt 2))
  -1
))

(print "pivotidx:" pivotidx " ")
(if (> pivotidx -1)
  ((def pivotval (nth arr pivotidx))
  (println "pivotval:" pivotval " ")
  (def right (filter #(> % pivotval ) arr))
  (def left (filter #(< % pivotval) arr))
  (println "left" left "right" right)
  (concat (qsort left) [pivot] (qsort right))
  )
  arr
)
) 


(defn sortme [] (qsort [3 5 8 9 1 7 12 13 2 14 0]))
```

Comment: In the code snippet `(concat (qsort left) [pivot] (qsort right))` - where is `pivot` defined?

Comment: You can find a quicksort implementation at http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithms/Quicksort#Clojure

Comment: It is erroneous to use def to define a local variable (this is a common mistake for Clojure beginners).  Please try using let (http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/let) instead.

Comment: Thx guys :) I read some clojure books but writing code is another story :)

Comment: FYI, the "Joy of Clojure" (though not naive) has a great lazy, tail recursive quicksort implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just using let instead of def properly does the right thing:

```
(defn qsort [arr]
(println "arr" arr)
(let 
 [
  cnt (count arr)
  pivotidx (if (> cnt 1) (int (/ cnt 2)) -1)
 ]
(print "pivotidx:" pivotidx " ")

(if (> pivotidx -1) 
 (let
   [
    pivotval (nth arr pivotidx)
    right (filter #(> % pivotval ) arr)
    left (filter #(< % pivotval) arr)
   ] 
 (println "pivotval:" pivotval " ")
 (println "left" left "right" right)
 (concat (qsort left) [pivotval] (qsort right))
 )
 arr) ))
```

And then

```
(qsort [3 5 8 9 1 7 12 13 2 14 0])
```

returns:

```
(0 1 2 3 5 7 8 9 12 13 14)
```

Comment: Might also want to get the pivots `pivots (filter #(== % pivotval)` then include them in concat `(concat (quicksort left) pivots (quicksort right))`

Answer (score 4):

Other answers have already done a good job of describing the "right" way of doing things, which coincidentally also fix your issue. However, your NPE is caused by

```
((def pivotval (nth arr pivotidx))
 ...more stuff...)
```

You cannot simply use `()` to group elements: `(foo)` in lisp denotes calling the function `foo`; likewise, `((bar) (foo))` means:

1. Call `bar`, saving the result as `x`
2. Call `foo`. saving the result as `y`
3. Call the function `x` with argument `y`

Because `def` does not return a function, calling its result with six or seven arguments will cause a problem.

Instead, if you want to group things, you should use the `do` special form. `(do (foo) (bar))` means "call foo, then return the result of calling bar".

Comment: Thanks for explanation amalloy. Obviously I just start to learn Clojure, without you I would be doomed :)

Answer (score 1):

```
(defn qsort
  [l]
  (cond
    (empty? l) '()
    :else (let [f (first l)
                smaller (filter #(<= % f) (rest l))
                bigger (filter #(> % f) (rest l))]
            (concat (qsort smaller) [f] (qsort bigger)))))
```

Comment: It might help next time if you add a little explanation to your answer.

Comment: out of interest, why did you use (cond...:else and not (if ?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like if array is length 1 then:

- pivotidx will be 0
- pivotval will be the first (only) item
- right and left will therefore both be empty (nil)
- hence you get a null pointer exception on the next recursion (probably when you try to count the length of nil....)

Some tips / other bugs to fix

- Put the test for nil or empty lists at the beginning of the function
- Don't use def inside a function - use (let [name value] ...) instead
- I think your partitioning logic will miss out duplicates of the pivot - woth checking this case!
- Not sure why you are taking the pivot value to be in the middle of the array, it's usually easiest just to use (first arr) as the pivot. The obnly case you want to pick the middle value is where you know the data is already nearly sorted....